# Extracting number format from string variable

Tags: database

I am working with a dataset that has over 45,000 variables in R. I am trying to create a new column from the title column. Here are two examples of the title column:

```
DIRECTIVE **2001/110/CE** DU CONSEIL DU 20 D<U+00C9>CEMBRE 2001 RELATIVE AU MIEL

Directive **2010/33/UE** de la Commission du 21<U+00A0>mai 2010 rectifiant la version espagnole de la directive<U+00A0>2001/112/CE du Conseil relative aux jus de fruits et <U+00E0> certains produits similaires destin<U+00E9>s <U+00E0> l'alimentation humaine
```

I want to create a new column from the data that is in bold but do not know how to get R to read and sort through the data.

Comment: What do you mean by you "do not know how to get R Studio to read and sort through the data"? Is this data in a file? Do you not know how to read files into R? How much R do you know? How far have you got? Does the data have 45,000 *rows* or 45,000 *columns*?

Comment: This is data from an excel file. So far, I have uploaded the excel file correctly.

Comment: This file has 45,000 rows and I am trying to detect a pattern from the title column. In the string variable, I need to extract the pattern: 2001/84/CE and what I do not understand is how to get R to detect the pattern. I have tried this code: str_detect(string, pattern, ignore.case = TRUE, data$Title, "([0-9]{4})[/.]([0-9]{2})[/.]([ce])") but I get the following error message:Error in str_detect(...) : 
  unused arguments (ignore.case = TRUE, data$Title, "([0-9]{4})[/.]([0-9]{2})[/.]([ce])")

Comment: You're supposed to put the string and the pattern in the place where the words "string" and "pattern" are. like: `str_detect("my string","[a-z]*"). You need to scale back a bit and read up on general data handling and string processing in R.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Yes, I am very new to this, so I will look at more background info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways. The more scalable way would perhaps be to use regex.

I was trying to create a regex, but I am personally not very good at it, so it has some faults.

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("\\d{4}\\/\\d{3}/[A-Za-z]{2}", string))
```

would work for string one, but give the wrong result for string 2. Perhaps other can improve it.

The other way, is to find patterns in the title column. If the first word is always `directive` then:

```
 trimws(substr(string,10,21))
```

would more consistent results. All you have to do is to trim the white spaces from your resultant column as I have using `trimws()`.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking at the string package now and feel like that put me on the right track but I am still having some troubles with it. Unfortunately, directive is not always the first word, so I am trying to get R to detect the number format of ####/##/xx